# How can I prevent iPad web app from moving whilst allowing internal elements to scroll?

Tags: ipad, web, scroll

I've been developing an iPad web app over the past three days, and I'm trying to have internal horizontal scrolling, without allowing the rest of the page to move/zoom in ect. Essentially I want to lock it to specific co-ordinates, whilst allowing certain elements to scroll. If you're on an iPad you can see it here: http://streamerforipad.webs.com/app.html. It'll look kinda weird on a desktop. Also, sorry for my abysmal coding skills, I plan to clean it up with external CSS at some point.

P.S. Remember this is a *web app* so native code is a no-go.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable scrolling within certain element areas using the following:

```
$("element,element2").bind("touchmove",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```